# WCF ensure that the necessary enum values are present

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, enums

I'm trying to serialize enum values which potentially do not exist yet.
I have an existing project which has several enums in our datacontract for simplicity reason I display one like so:

```
public partial class TestDTO : ITestDTO
{
    public DeleteMe DeleteMeEnum { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public enum DeleteMe 
{
    [EnumMember]
    Deleted = 0,
}
```

Our application has a hidden internal wcf layer which our public web api accesses. A sample Service contract looks like so:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    TestDTO GetTestDTO();
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public TestDTO GetTestDTO()
    {
        return new TestDTO() { DeleteMeEnum = (DeleteMe)2 };
    }
}
```

When I call this method from WebApi obviously I get the classic error:

> Enum value '2' is invalid for type 'DeleteMe' and cannot be serialized. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute.

I can't go and change all of the enums now because we have a massive project, and replacing them would be too much, Also replacing all of our Service Contracts with a new Attibute would be too much.

Does anyone know of a way I can fix this globally, such as replacing the default XMLSerializer with a custom XMLSerializer?

Comment: Have you marked each instance of the enum with a `[DataMember]` attribute?

Comment: @ste-fu I'm trying to serialize members that are a value represtation of an enum that doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry - I'm a bit confused - how do you expect casting to a value that doesn't exist to work full stop?

Comment: @ste-fu c# allows any int based enum to be casted to an int value enum, so I would like to override the serializer to cast all enums to their int value, and when they are deserialize they are casted back to the enum in this case like so (DeleteMe)2

Comment: Why use enumerations at all if you are going to accept unknown values? If you need something to make managing changes in enumerations easier, then consider [T4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @R. Richards, Agreed I am not the original architect I am maintaining a massive solution,  I do not want to have to write another roslyn solution to replace all these values, I'm looking for a easy way to replace the datacontractserializer or some other work around

Comment: @Richards, we are using T4 already, but we have a custom context which automatically casts enums from the database, so they are being casted to invalid enums.  If a users add a new enum in the database it automatically resolved but unless we deploy our application breaks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a nice way to handle this once your application is released. However if you plan for the situation ahead of time, it can be handled.

So for the example above, you can do this:

```
public partial class TestDTO : ITestDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "DeleteMeEnum")]
    private string DeleteMeEnumString 
    {
         get { return DeleteMeEnum.ToString(); }
         set {
              DeleteMe _enum;
              if (!Enum.TryParse(value, out _enum))
              {
                  _enum = <default value>;
              }
              DeleteMeEnum = _enum;
         }
    }   

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public DeleteMe DeleteMeEnum { get; set; }
}
```